# Remove XML namespace from child element

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization

I'm not sure quite how to do this but i need to generate an excel file as follows

```
<abc: Declarant>
<Type>Test</Type>
<ReferenceNo>TESTREF</ReferenceNo>
<Provider>Me</Provider>
</abc: Declarant>
```

Note how the namespace is only prefixed on the higher level. I've no problem serializing this either with or without the namespace prefix but cant seem to get it without.

Heres what i have before my serialisation

```
XmlSerializer x = new XmlSerializer(t.GetType());
            System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(
            path);
            XmlSerializerNamespaces ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
            ns.Add("abc", "http://www.iwebcms.com");

            x.Serialize(file, t,ns);
```

and declarant is as follows

[XmlElement(ElementName = "Declarant", Namespace = "http://www.iwebcms.com")]
        public Declarant declarant { get; set; }

```
[Serializable()]
    public class Declarant
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Type")]
        public string Type { get; set; }

        [XmlElement(ElementName = "ReferenceNo")]
        public string ReferenceNo { get; set; }

        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Provider")]
        public string Provider { get; set; }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated :(

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i ended up just looping through the file as raw text and replacing the namespace where i needed to - nasty but got me going....

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be working with two different Namespaces, in one place you have it defined as http://www.mysite, in the other it is defined as http://www.iwebcms.com. Ensure that you are using the proper namespace everywhere.

Comment: sorry, wouldnt let me use mysite again for some reason - i'll adjust!